# Generate "Report Export Date" Value on a Report and Associate Value with Each Record on Report...Feasible?

Tags: formula, date, reports-api, report-builder

Is there anyway to populate the date or datetime a report is exported within a report...a field value that will be associated with every record in the report?

For instance could i use the a field formula or build a formula within the report that leverages Report API "LastRunDate" and have it populate every time i run a report and have that value appear associated with each record in the report?

I am not sure if this possible...looking for input about feasibility. Thank you!

Comment: why not have a custom formula field on the Object called `Today__c` with value = `TODAY()` and include that field in the report's columns?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that comes to mind (unless using something like Conga Composer) would be to add to each of your objects subject to this reporting requirement a custom formula field called `Today__c` with value = `TODAY()`. Then include this field on your report output.  If you don't like this column title, name the custom field `Reporting Date`

If you want date/time, use formula `NOW()`